# OnClickListener in RecyclerView having image, text

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to  show another activity when object of recycler view is clicked. For eg: if I clicked "dd" text or"image of that line" then I should go to activity named "AbcActivity".

It went to many site, saw youtube tutorial but didn't helped. please help me with it. Please help me out this is my last hope :(

I'm beginner in this, It'd be great if you can provide project.

This is main activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WordAdapter.OnNoteListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();


        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "dd"));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "ss"));

        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(wordList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
    }
}
```

WordAdapter:

```java
public class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.viewholder> {

    private List<Word> wordList;
    private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;

    public WordAdapter(List<Word> wordList, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
        this.wordList = wordList;
        this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);
        return new viewholder(view, mOnNoteListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = wordList.get(position).getImageResource();
        String title = wordList.get(position).getTitle();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wordList.size();
    }

    class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView title;

        OnNoteListener onNoteListener;
        public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
            this.onNoteListener = onNoteListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void setData(int resource, String titleText){
            imageView.setImageResource(resource);
            title.setText(titleText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnNoteListener {
        void onNoteClick(int position);
    }
}
```

This is word:

```java
public class Word implements Parcelable {

   private int imageResource;
   private String title;

    public Word(int imageResource, String title) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected Word(Parcel in) {
        imageResource = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Word> CREATOR = new Creator<Word>() {
        @Override
        public Word createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Word(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Word[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Word[size];
        }
    };

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(imageResource);
        parcel.writeString(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the implementation for the method onNoteClick()??

Comment: make your viewholder class implement the interface method.and after that  choose which activity you want to go based upon the adapter position

Comment: Hi Jeeva, I'm beginner in this filed, can you please provide me the project made in recycler view by adding image & text and OnCreate method? please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works to a big percent fine. Not sure what is the problem. Maybe you have a problem when starting the new activity but surely this code has no issues.
I will post below your example with small modifications to the ViewHolder.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WordAdapter.OnNoteListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<>();


        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "dd"));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "ss"));
        wordList.add(new Word(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "cc"));


        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.addItems(wordList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on the position:" + position);
    }
}

    public class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Word> wordList;
    private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;

    public WordAdapter(List<Word> wordList, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
        this.wordList = wordList;
        this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
    }

    public WordAdapter(OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
        this(new ArrayList<Word>(), onNoteListener);
    }

    public void addItems(List<Word> items) {
        wordList.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        wordList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, mOnNoteListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = wordList.get(position).getImageResource();
        String title = wordList.get(position).getTitle();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wordList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView title;

        private OnNoteListener onNoteListener;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
            this.onNoteListener = onNoteListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void setData(int resource, String titleText) {
            imageView.setImageResource(resource);
            title.setText(titleText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnNoteListener {
        void onNoteClick(int position);
    }
}
```

The word class stays the same. 
Now, regarding the xml, I put some quick stuff below(list_item.xml):

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_green_100"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Word 1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:contentDescription="Icon"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/word"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below you can find a screenshot of the click events. 
[image]

Now, knowing that click events work do whatever you want, startActivity, Log, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei, can you please help me with one more problem? please assume I want to navigate to activity named "abc" when i clicked the word "dd" of list what should I do? can you please give me code and say where should i keep that? please? please?

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it. Now, some things you should try yourself if you want to learn. As you can see nobody is giving you the project because here you get help not an entire project to copy.

Comment: You could ask a second question and put a link here or wait for somebody else to answer.

Comment: @Rajana , if the code works fine then accept the answer.

Comment: I really wanted to learn about specific(for each list) ClickListener but the main problem is i can't find any reliable source, some of them are outdated whereas some of were not what I expected. I've also searched in Udacity, android's codelabs but can find what I expected and didn't understood of android's website. and as I'm beginner, I've not that much of idea to do myself :(.                                      COULD YO PLEASE SUGGEST ME ANY LINK TO LERN. It's been abt 17 i started this jouney.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `OnClickListener` for your `viewHolder`'s `itemView`.

This will start the `AbcActivity` when you click on the `imageView` of the `viewholder`.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = wordList.get(position).getImageResource();
        String title = wordList.get(position).getTitle();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title);

        // @ADDED
        // viewholder.itemView or viewholder.title will work too
        viewholder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            void onClick(View v) {
                // start activity

                Context context = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();              
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AbcActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: it is not working, can you please provide me a project please?

Comment: Is it not starting the `AbcActivity`? Have you tried testing if clicking the image fires the `onClick` block.

Comment: yes I tried, didn't worked :-( the code give by Andrei is working fine and showing list clicked in logcat, can you please suggest how to replace thant logcat with intent so i can navigate to another activity when i clicked specific object of list?

Answer (score 0):

You've done almost everything.

All that remains is actually handling the click event that the listener you passed to your adapter is letting you know in the activity.

Change

```
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {


}
```

To this

```
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, AbcActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

in your activity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, AbcActivity.class);

Comment: Thank you Sajal Gupta Sir, it worked. Can you please also say me how can I click each list view and go to other activity I wants, lest assume the list i clicked is "ss" and i want to go to activity named "sgActivity" ?

Comment: Hey @Rajana you can edit the signature of your listener to something like

void onNoteClick(int position, String title)

and then pass relevant information to finally use it in your activity's listener implementation to open required activities.